# Java Hibernate DataException: cannot be converted to BIGINT

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I'm trying to join one table, with two other tables, using a single column in Java using Hibernate and JPQL.

For example, I have `table A` with an `id` column. I want to join `table B` and `table C` with `table A` on the `id` column.

However, when I try to do that I get the following error:
`org.hibernate.exception.DataException: The value supplied cannot be converted to BIGINT`. I have seen some answer say that there may be null values, but these id columns are primary id columns, and contain no nulls.

My code is as follows:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = fetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private TableB tableB

@OneToOne(fetch = fetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private TableC tableC
```

When I remove one of the two joins everything works fine again.

What am I doing wrong that's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type `id` is, but is but I think it must be a `Long` in order for Hibernate to convert it to a `BIGINT`